# C# struct default values

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts a struct that contains many fields with basic datatypes.

I want to pass mostly defaults but with a couple tweaks, but I understand basic fields in a struct declaration can't contain default value declarations, e.g. `struct S{ int a = 42 }`.

Right now it goes like this:

```
OptionsStruct options = OptionStructDefaults;
options.itemA = 2;
options.itemQ = 2; // ... itemB, itemR, itemAZ12, etc.

SetOptions(options);
```

However, it feels weird to have `OptionsStructDefaults` information separate from the `OptionsStruct` declaration...

It feels like there'd be a way to do something like this?

```
SetOptions( new OptionsStruct(){
    itemA = 2,
    itemQ = 2,
    // ...all other fields have default values.
})
```

Or:

```
SetOptions( new OptionsStruct(useDefaults:true){
    itemA = 2,
    itemQ = 2,
});
```

Alternatively, is there a reason why separately specified struct defaults is ultimately the way to do things?

Comment: Could you use a constructor in the struct that sets most defaults but accepts a few optional params?

Comment: `struct OptionsStruct { public static OptionStruct Default(int itemA = 2, int itemB = 2) { return new ... } }` and use it like: `SetOptions(OptionStruct.Default(itemB: 4))`

Comment: Sorry, in using `item Q ` in the example I meant to demonstrate that I'd like to tweak -any- field, not just a couple specific ones. Will clarify in question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** In C# 10+ (.NET 6+) this limitation is lifted. You now **can** have default constructors on structs, and you also **can** initialize fields and properties in place. Write your struct as if it was a class, and it will work:

```cs
public struct OptionsStruct
{
    public int ItemA { get; set; } = 2;
    public int ItemQ { get; set; } = 2;
}
```

```cs
    SetOptions(new OptionsStruct()
    {
        ItemA = 3,
        // ...all other fields have default values.
    });
```

However, there are 2 gotchas to be aware of:

- If you have no constructors or a parameter-less constructor on your struct, the field and property initializations will work fine. But, they won't work if you have a constructor with parameters but no parameter-less constructors. If you have a with-parameter constructor, also write a parameter-less constructor (even if it's empty), so when you write `new MyStruct()`, the fields and properties are initialized as you expect. (This behavior is there to keep backward compatibility with the previous behavior of not calling a constructor when all parameters are optional. See the last code block on this answer for an example.)

  ```cs
  public struct NoConstructor
  {
      public int Item { get; set; } = 42;
  }

  public struct ParameterlessConstructor
  {
      public int Item { get; set; } = 42;

      public ParameterlessConstructor() { }
  }

  public struct WithParameterConstructor
  {
      public int Item { get; set; } = 42;

      public WithParameterConstructor(int item)
      {
          Item = item;
      }
  }

  public struct BothConstructors
  {
      public int Item { get; set; } = 42;

      public BothConstructors() { }

      public BothConstructors(int item)
      {
          Item = item;
      }
  }
  ```

  ```cs
      Console.WriteLine(new NoConstructor().Item); // 42
      Console.WriteLine(new ParameterlessConstructor().Item); // 42
      Console.WriteLine(new WithParameterConstructor().Item); // 0
      Console.WriteLine(new BothConstructors().Item); // 42
  ```
- The parameter-less constructor is not guaranteed to be always called, so don't rely on your fields and properties being always initialized. If you create an array of a struct, like `new MyStruct[5]`, or if you use `default` or `default(MyStruct)`, no constructor will be called and the field and properties will be initialized to default values (`0` or `false` or `null`), just like how it would be before C# 10.

  ```cs
  public struct MyStruct
  {
      public int FortyTwo { get; } = 42;

      public int GetFortyThree()
      {
          return FortyTwo + 1;
      }
  }

  public class SomeClass
  {
      MyStruct myStruct; // not initialized, same as default(MyStruct)

      public int GetFortyThree()
      {
          return myStruct.GetFortyThree();
      }
  }
  ```

  ```cs
      Console.WriteLine(new MyStruct().GetFortyThree()); // 43
      Console.WriteLine(default(MyStruct).GetFortyThree()); // 1
      var array = new MyStruct[5];
      Console.WriteLine(array[0].GetFortyThree()); // 1
      Console.WriteLine(new SomeClass().GetFortyThree()); // 1
  ```

Here's the link to the docs on the new C# 10 / .NET 6 feature: [Parameterless constructors and field initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#parameterless-constructors-and-field-initializers)

**For C# 9 and below, read on...**

---

The limitation on `struct`s is that you cannot have a **default** constructor. So you cannot set default values to the fields and properties (because that is compiled into the default constructor).

But you **can** have a non-default constructor, i.e. a constructor that takes parameters.

So you can have a `struct` like this:

```cs
public struct OptionsStruct
{
    public int ItemA { get; set; }
    public int ItemQ { get; set; }

    public OptionsStruct(bool useDefaults)
    {
        if (useDefaults)
        {
            ItemA = 2;
            ItemQ = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            ItemA = 0;
            ItemQ = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it as you wrote:

```cs
    SetOptions(new OptionsStruct(useDefaults:true)
    {
        ItemA = 3,
        // ...all other fields have default values.
    });
```

---

Another way to go is to have a `static` method that sets the default values:

```cs
public struct OptionsStruct
{
    public int ItemA { get; set; }
    public int ItemQ { get; set; }

    public static OptionsStruct GetDefault()
    {
        return new OptionsStruct()
        {
            ItemA = 2;
            ItemQ = 2;
        };
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
    var options = OptionsStruct.GetDefault();
    options.ItemA = 3;
    SetOptions(options);
```

---

If the number of your properties is not too much, you can also use a constructor with optional parameters:

```cs
public struct OptionsStruct
{
    public int ItemA { get; set; }
    public int ItemQ { get; set; }

    public OptionsStruct(int itemA = 2, int itemQ = 2)
    {
        ItemA = itemA;
        ItemQ = itemQ;
    }
}
```

But it will only be called if you give it at least one parameter:

```cs
    var options1 = new OptionsStruct(); // The "default" constructor is called, so everythng will be 0.
    Console.WriteLine(options1.ItemA); // 0
    Console.WriteLine(options1.ItemQ); // 0

    var options2 = new OptionsStruct(3); // Everything works as expected.
    Console.WriteLine(options1.ItemA); // 3
    Console.WriteLine(options1.ItemQ); // 2
```

Comment: Ah, I had tried `Options(bool defaults=true){...}` without luck and thought having to be explicit about it all the time ( `new Options(true)`) seemed fishy. 

Constructor with optional params allowing `new Options(itemQ:42);` feels pretty good! Indeed it seems like it could be a little clunky with lots of options but could be worse. 

And I didn't realize you could have static methods on a struct! That'd be really handy  for supporting different pre-made option sets!

Comment: In my opinion, it seems it has become too easy to add features to C# now that they have everything as managed code, as this new C# 10 feature will add more pitfalls for developers and will rely on tooling to help developers. I assume this should be paired with code analyzers or plugins for Visual Studio / Rider to highlight places where you're using a struct with default values where they will not be applied, and in my opinion this is the wrong direction to go.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen When you have a value-type structure in a language, there is no better way of adding a parameter-less constructor but this. Other solutions (like what C++ does) have bad performance implications. And not running the constructor when it is not **explicitly** called is very understandable (and is probably less confusing than the last code block on my answer). Overall, I think this is a very useful and very sensible feature to add to C#. (Well, except for the strange behavior when you have a constructor, but no parameter-less ones.)

Comment: ... and the behavior when you use it in an array, or as a field in a class, or in any of the other cases where your fields will not be initialized. I will keep my opinion, this is not a good feature in my mind, it adds a minefield of cases where the new stuff will not be executed, and it's not at all clear from your code whether it will be or won't be.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is clear from the code whether it is executed. If you write `new MyStruct()` explicitly, it will be executed. If you don't, it won't be executed. You can see explicitly in your code that you are calling the constructor or not.