# CS0171 A constructor in a struct must initialize all fields in the struct

Tags: c#, struct, c#-10.0

```
struct Mutable {
    private int x;
    public Mutable() { }  //Compiler Error CS0171

}
```

So if i declare a constructor for a struct, It says that all the fields must be assigned but I am thinking why cant't the inline initializer just DEFAULT the field' values to their defaults?
I mean when no Constructor is specified the inline initializer does default the fields' values to their defaults.

Comment: Traditionally, you could not create a default constructor for a struct. Now you can, but with the restriction that you must do the work that compiler did for you before (by initializing everything) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct. Also, you should read up on why mutable structs are a bad idea.

Comment: Can you please [edit] post to clarify what you want to figure out? So far it reads "I don't like C# designers' choices" which is purely opinion based...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# struct default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776224/c-sharp-struct-default-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it can, but it is planned for the next language version - C# 11. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#auto-default-struct):

> ### Auto-default struct

> The C# 11 compiler ensures that all fields of a `struct` type are initialized to their default value as part of executing a constructor. This change means any field or auto property not initialized by a constructor is automatically initialized by the compiler. Structs where the constructor doesn't definitely assign all fields now compile, and any fields not explicitly initialized are set to their default value. You can read more about how this change affects struct initialization in the article on [structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#struct-initialization-and-default-values).

Read more:

- [Proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5737)

Comment: Okay thank you but Why woudn't they do this much earlier, like in classes?

Comment: 'Cause (that's the whole answer). Really, you are asking a question like "why doesn't Hyundai sell a covertible?"

Comment: Okay, got It, I am sorry.

Comment: @EricMovsessian reasons can be plentiful - didn't think of (very doubtful though), considered to be better to be better option, considered to low impact feature to implement in that language version release time window, etc.